# Spring boot component scan include a single class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations, component-scan

I am using spring component scan to auto detect beans as:

```
@ComponentScan({"com.org.x, com.org.y"})
```

The issue is I want all classes in `com.org.x` to be scanned but I want a single class, `com.org.y.SomeService.class`, alone to be scanned from `com.org.y`

How can I achieve this ?

Also apart from using context scan, how can I created this bean and inject in the application context ?

Comment: Why use a scan if you just want a single bean. Just define your bean using an `@Bean` annotated method in your configuration class. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-basic-concepts

Comment: @JBNizet can you provide me a snippet for it

Comment: I included a link to the documentation, which contains snippets, explanations, and everything.

Comment: @JBNizet can you post it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just define your bean using a method annotated with `@Bean` in your configuration class, as explained in [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-basic-concepts).

Comment: What about `@Component` that has `@Autowired` fields?

Comment: Yep. Same for the non-default constructor: if the `SomeService` has parameters in constructor you have to copy them to the instantiating `@Bean` method.

Answer (score 30):

`@Import(com.org.y.SomeService.class)` works in my case (even when `SomeService` is a `@Service`, not a `@Configuration`)

Comment: I didn't know that one can even import `@Service`s. This is especially helpful if one can't call a constructor due to visibility restrictions.

Comment: or `@Import(value = { Class1.class, Class2.class })`