# Have my Spring test slice scan a single class instead of the whole package

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing

I was asked to create integration tests for an existing SpringBoot project, whose organisation is not as modular as I would prefer. For example, there is a package yielding all repositories associated with all services. This became a problem for me when I was attempting to create a `@WebMvcTest` test slice, because when I use `@ComponentScan`, `@EnableJpaRepositories`, `@EntityScan` to read my target classes it ends up scanning all other unnecessary ones that share the same package.

Since changing the project structure is not really a decision I can make on my own, my question is whether it is possible to have my test scan pick a specific class and disregard all others within the same package?

Thank you for your attention

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37757768/spring-boot-component-scan-include-a-single-class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was finally able to achieve all the required filtering, thanks to Josef's answer and these:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/21022853/4828060,
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8648748/4828060

**Components and Services** can be configured to yield filters hence we can specify our target services and controllers and exclude everything else at the same time:

```
 @ComponentScan(
        basePackageClasses = {
                MyTargetService.class,
                MyTargetController.class
        },
        useDefaultFilters = false,
        includeFilters = {
                @ComponentScan.Filter(type = ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = MyTargetService.class),
                @ComponentScan.Filter(type = ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = MyTargetController.class)

        }
)
```

**Repositories.** This is unlikely to work for repositories, but fortunately the `@EnableJpaRepositories` supports the same type of filters:

```
  @EnableJpaRepositories(
       basePackageClasses = {
            MyTargetRepository.class
       },
       includeFilters = {
            @ComponentScan.Filter(type = ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = MyTargetRepository.class)
       }
  )
```

**Entities.** This part is more tricky because @EntityScan does not support these filters. Although the entities do not reference Spring beans, I prefer loading only the entities necessary for my test. I was not able to find any annotation for entities that supports filtering, but we can filter them programmatically using a `PersistenceUnitPostProcessor` in our `EntityManagerFactory`. Here is my full solution:

```
   //add also the filtered @ComponentScan and @EnableJpaRepositories annotations here
   @Configuration
   public class MyConfig {

    //here we specify the packages of our target entities
    private static String[] MODEL_PACKAGES = {
            "com.full.path.to.entity.package1",
            "com.full.path.to.entity.package2"
    };

    //here we specify our target entities
    private static Set<String> TARGET_ENTITIES = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(
            "com.full.path.to.entity.package1.MyTargetEntity1",
            "com.full.path.to.entity.package2.MyTargetEntity2"
    ));

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        return builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {

        ReflectionsPersistenceUnitPostProcessor reflectionsPersistenceUnitPostProcessor = new ReflectionsPersistenceUnitPostProcessor();

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan(MODEL_PACKAGES);
        factory.setDataSource(getDataSource());
        factory.setPersistenceUnitPostProcessors(reflectionsPersistenceUnitPostProcessor);
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();

        return factory.getObject();
    }


    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
        return txManager;
    }

    public class ReflectionsPersistenceUnitPostProcessor implements PersistenceUnitPostProcessor {

        @Override
        public void postProcessPersistenceUnitInfo(MutablePersistenceUnitInfo pui) {

            Reflections r = new Reflections("", new TypeAnnotationsScanner());
            Set<Class<?>> entityClasses = r.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Entity.class, true);
            Set<Class<?>> mappedSuperClasses = r.getTypesAnnotatedWith(MappedSuperclass.class, true);

            pui.getManagedClassNames().clear(); //here we remove all entities

            //here we add only the ones we are targeting
            for (Class<?> clzz : mappedSuperClasses) {
                if (TARGET_ENTITIES.contains(clzz.getName())) {
                    pui.addManagedClassName(clzz.getName());
                }
            }
            for (Class<?> clzz : entityClasses) {
                if (TARGET_ENTITIES.contains(clzz.getName())) {
                    pui.addManagedClassName(clzz.getName());
                }
            }

        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ComponentScan` can work with slices. - It's actually configured on `SpringBootApplication` annotation itself. The part that makes test slices work with `ComponentScan` is `TypeExcludeFilter`:

```
@ComponentScan(
    basePackages = "com.mycompany.someotherpackage",
    excludeFilters = {
      @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM, classes = TypeExcludeFilter.class),
    })
```

Comment: Thanks! How about with entities? If I have a package with numerous entities but I am interested in only one of them?

Comment: @JoãoMatos Unfortunately I don't have any experience with that. Usually entities are referencing each other so more of them must be loaded anyway. But at the same time - there's no expense in loading them all apart from time spent on generating tables in DB etc. They are not referencing Spring beans so future changes should not break your existing tests.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [João Matos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60280507/1373031) answer and [a response to a github issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/13339#issuecomment-394757267) I was able to put together a shorter complete solution. The difference here is that all of the hibernate setup is left to Spring Boot. Following sample limits the repositories to MyEntityRepository and entities to MyEntity.

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyEntityRepositoryTest.TestConfiguration.class)
public class MyRepositoryTest {

    @Configuration
    @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = MyEntityRepository.class, 
        includeFilters = {
            @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = MyEntityRepository.class) })
    static class TestConfiguration {

        public class CustomPersistenceUnitPostProcessor implements PersistenceUnitPostProcessor {

            @Override
            public void postProcessPersistenceUnitInfo(MutablePersistenceUnitInfo pui) {
                pui.addManagedClassName(MyEntity.class.getName());
            }

        }

        @Component
        class CustomBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

            @Override
            public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
                if (bean instanceof LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean) {
                    ((LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean) bean)
                            .setPersistenceUnitPostProcessors(new CustomPersistenceUnitPostProcessor());
                }
                return bean;
            }

        }
    }

    @Autowired
    MyEntityRepository myEntityRepository;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        ...
    }

}
```